# Regarding mDNS observations on Wireshark

Tags: dns, opc-ua, mdns, dns-sd

I am a beginner here, would like to clarify a few things.
I have a server (OPC UA) running on my system, and the specification says  it is announcing itself on the local link using DNS SRV records. On doing some research, I figured that mDNS is used along with DNS-SD for service discovery in local networks. The mDNS specifies the terms probing and announcement. I really am not understand the same on the wireshark log when i run the server.
Does the resource record mean, the different types of records (A, SRV,TXT,PTR) for the service(_opcua-tcp._tcp.local?)

Since it should be an announcement on the network, should it just not be a SRV query informing the service name with the port and host information?

When there is a single host and single service on the host, what are the implications of Multicast probe and announce?

Please let me know.

Attahced is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQFRM.png)